# Xcode Interface Builder Pin Tool makes UITableView disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have a UITableView and I want it to hit the upper bar, the sides of the view and the Seek Bar below. When I add constraints with the Pin Tool, the UITableView simply disappears and I get no log output.

I use the Pin Tool like shown here:

[image]

After this, the table disappears. Why? Here is another picture of my setup, it's literally just up/down/left/right constraints, nothing else, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving the top bar some constraints and **giving the UITableView** a "width" constraint - I have no idea why that works but now it scales nicely for every display size

[image]